# How to remove all struct with same value from an array

Tags: arrays, c, struct, element

I'm working on my C programming skills, but i'm kinda stuck on a problem:

I have an array of Animal structs, which i can add animals to. One of the values is the animalId, however, there is no check for duplicate id's. So for example, I can add three dogs with the same id, but they can be on different positions within the array.

I'm trying to write a function which lets me remove alle the animals with the same id from the array. With the code below, the program only removes the first animal with the found id. Also when I try to remove the same id again, the program does not find the rest. For the return I want to return the total number of animals removed.

Can you guys give me some tips what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: moved the line "*newNumberOfAnimalsPresent = numberOfAnimalsPresent - 1;" outside of the j loop.

```
int removeAnimal(int animalId, Animal *animalArray, size_t numberOfAnimalsPresent, size_t *newNumberOfAnimalsPresent)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfAnimalsPresent; ++i)
    {
        if (animalId == animalArray[i].Id)
        {
            for (size_t j = i; j < numberOfAnimalsPresent - 1; ++j)
            { 
                animalArray[j] = animalArray[j + 1];              
            }
            *newNumberOfAnimalsPresent = numberOfAnimalsPresent - 1; 
        }
    }
    return numberOfAnimalsPresent - *newNumberOfAnimalsPresent;
}
```

Comment: What would be really good is if the data-structure didn't let duplicate id's present in the first place, like `unordered_map`.

Comment: Yeah, that would be good, but that is something that is out of my hands :)

Comment: The outer loop has issues.  When the ID is found, remaining items are moved back so `i` shouldn't be incremented.  Also, when items are removed, the number of remaining items decreases and the loop condition needs to reflect that (by decreasing `numberOfAnimalsPresent` for each removal, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two counters to iterate through the array. `check` is always incremented so every array element is checked. `good` is only incremented when there is no match so it reflects the array element that are good and will be kept.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int Id;
} Animal;

int removeAnimal(int animalId, Animal *animalArray, size_t numberOfAnimalsPresent, size_t *newNumberOfAnimalsPresent)
{
    size_t good = 0;
    size_t check = 0;
    for ( good = 0, check = 0; check < numberOfAnimalsPresent; ++check)
    {
        if (animalId != animalArray[check].Id)//not a match
        {
            if ( good != check) {//not equal
                animalArray[good] = animalArray[check];//make a copy
            }
            ++good;//increment
        }
    }
    *newNumberOfAnimalsPresent = good;
    return check - good;
}

int main ( void) {
    Animal pets[10] = {
        { 1}
        , { 2}
        , { 3}
        , { 4}
        , { 5}
        , { 2}
        , { 7}
        , { 8}
        , { 9}
        , { 2}
    };
    int duplicates = 0;
    size_t elements = 0;
    size_t show = 0;

    duplicates = removeAnimal ( 2, pets, 10, &elements);
    printf ( "2 found %d times\n", duplicates);

    while ( show < elements) {
        printf ( "pet[%zu] id is %d\n", show, pets[show].Id);
        ++show;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this explenation really helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`*newNumberOfAnimalsPresent = numberOfAnimalsPresent - 1;` should go after the j loop no?

Comment: Yes :-)   The code is incorrectly reducing the number of animals present on each iteration of the copy rather than after the copy is done.

Comment: That did solve part of the problem, thanks :) But it still only removes the first id found, and not all of the id's present in the array

Comment: You are not removing anything. If the array only has one animal, only newNumberOfAnimalsPresent is decremented. How are you supposed to mark an animal as removed? Set its id to zero?

Answer (score 0):

Since you will only iterate over every item if there is no removal, I think it is better to forget the for loop and use a while instead:

```
int removeAnimal(int animalId, Animal *animalArray, size_t numberOfAnimalsPresent, size_t *newNumberOfAnimalsPresent)
{
    *newNumberOfAnimalsPresent = numberOfAnimalsPresent;
    int i = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        if (*newNumberOfAnimalsPresent <= i)
        {
            break;
        }
        Animal animal = animalArray[i];
        if (animalId == animal.Id)
        {
            for (size_t j = i; j < *newNumberOfAnimalsPresent - 1; j++)
            {
                animalArray[j] = animalArray[j + 1];
            }
            (*newNumberOfAnimalsPresent)--;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return numberOfAnimalsPresent - *newNumberOfAnimalsPresent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! The while loop is a very nice solution!